# Import problems python module

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python project where I have this folder structure:

[image]

I'm currently editing the `operators.py` file and I get this error when I try to import a class from the  `hooks.py` file.

[image]

I really don't understand why I get this error since by putting the `__init__.py` file in  the `custom` folder I should have turned it into a python module.

Comment: `from dags.custom.hooks import TrediWSHook`, try to write oath from the source directory

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a PyCharm issue, not actually Python. I assume `dags` is the root folder for your project. If that's the case, right click on it -> Mark Directory as -> Sources Root

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it seems your **operators.py** file is int the same module as **hooks**, so :

```
from .hooks import TrediWSHook
```

Comment: It is in the same folder, so this solution won't work.

Comment: @PCM this solution works for me, so don't know why you say that.

Comment: Ok, my bad, but what the OP tried is similar - `from custom.hooks ...` is the same as `from .hooks ...` when they are in the same folder. So, that's why I said it won't make any difference